# Getting Null pointer exception while executing Hive query

Tags: hadoop, hiveql

My Hive insert query was working fine. I added one more column in the existing table and now I am getting following error:

```
Error: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.vector.VectorizedRowBatchCtx.allocateColumnVector(VectorizedRowBatchCtx.java:583)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.vector.VectorizedRowBatchCtx.addScratchColumnsToBatch(VectorizedRowBatchCtx.java:558)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.vector.VectorizedRowBatchCtx.createVectorizedRowBatch(VectorizedRowBatchCtx.java:321)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.VectorizedOrcInputFormat$VectorizedOrcRecordReader.createValue(VectorizedOrcInputFormat.java:110)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.VectorizedOrcInputFormat$VectorizedOrcRecordReader.createValue(VectorizedOrcInputFormat.java:50)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.CombineHiveRecordReader.createValue(CombineHiveRecordReader.java:80)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.CombineHiveRecordReader.createValue(CombineHiveRecordReader.java:41)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.shims.HadoopShimsSecure$CombineFileRecordReader.createValue(HadoopShimsSecure.java:194)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$TrackedRecordReader.createValue(MapTask.java:179)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:50)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:430)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:342)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:167)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1557)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:162)

FAILED: Execution Error, return code 2 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.MapRedTask
MapReduce Jobs Launched: 
Job 0: Map: 63  Reduce: 12   HDFS Read: 0 HDFS Write: 0 FAIL
Total MapReduce CPU Time Spent: 0 msec
```

Any help/reference is highly appreciated.

Comment: can you post your query.

Comment: Its working fine now after putting set hive.vectorized.execution.enabled=false; before query .